# Using regular expression to extract repeated phrase in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am attempting to locate(then extract) a repeated phrase by using the below code.  I require phrases beginning with "approximately" and ending in "closed".

For example "approximately $162.9 million in total assets and $144.5 million in total deposits was closed"

`str_locate(x,"(\b[Aa]pproximately\b)(.*)(\b[Cc]losed\b)")`

```
str_extract(x,"(\b[Aa]pproximately\b)(.*)(\b[Cc]losed\b)")
```

The above code returns NA for phrase start and end points.
Here is a sample of the character vector where the phrases are located.(it is a webpage of publicly available FDIC information)

"206-4662).\r\n\r\nDecember \r\n\r\n\r\n Western National Bank, Phoenix, AZ  with approximately $162.9 million in total assets and $144.5 million in total deposits was closed. Washington Federal, Seattle, WA has agreed to assume all deposits excluding certain brokered deposits.\r\n(PR-195-2011)   \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n Premier Community Bank of the Emerald Coast, Crestview, FL  with approximately $126.0 million in total assets and $112.1 million in total deposits was closed.  Summit Bank, N.A., Panama City, FL has agreed to assume all deposits.\r\n(PR-194-2011)"

I may be using reg expression incorrectly as i am new to it so any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

`\b` is ASCII backspace. You need to escape the backslashes if you want it to mean "word boundary":

```
str_locate(x,"(\\b[Aa]pproximately\\b)(.*)(\\b[Cc]losed\\b)")
```

Also, you don't need the parentheses around your keywords, unless you want to check their capitalization later. And you can match case-insensitively with the `(?i)` modifier when using the `perl()` function for your regexes.

Lastly, be aware that `.*` will not match if there are newlines between `approximately` and `closed` (this can be fixed with `(?s)`), and it may yield unwanted results if more than one pair of keywords is present in the string.

Therefore, you should probably change your regex to

```
str_locate(x, perl("(?is)\\bapproximately\\b(.*?)\\bclosed\\b"))
```

Comment: Thanks for swift response Tim,  Could you possibly elaborate on how to encompass the perl function within str_locate() ?  This particular package doesnt seems to have perl options within it

Comment: @user1176697: It isn't? But it's described [in the manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf), page 4.